# Powershell Script to See where AD security group is used?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a Security Group in AD and have no idea what it does. Is it possible, using Powershell (or otherwise) to see where on a network an Active Directory security group is used? Is Active Directory actually aware of what is authenticating to its Security Groups? Does it keep any kind of log of this?

My guess is that it is not possible, but open to hearing how it could be done.

Thanks

Comment: maybe in an audit log somewhere, but consider that every single NTFS directory having that group added explicitly would cause an auth lookup, the audit log would be insanely huge.

Comment: I don't even think that would do it, since I'm guessing it would show the accounts in the group authenticating, not the group itself. Best way to find out in my opinion? Ask your peers, and if nobody knows what it's for disable the group, and watch for what breaks.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I was thinking the same thing, even if there's a log that exists, it probably only shows the users. My feeling is the same thing, watch for what breaks.

Comment: You could potentially crawl a file share directory structure and dump all of the security group assignments for ACLs to a CSV. I did that once when I cleaned up AD groups at a job. But there's so many places an AD group could be used. SQL permissions, random applications for access mapping, etc. This is why a consistent naming structure for AD groups is needed, and documentation in the description/notes field of the groups.